# In pandas transform lambda function use if else to get 2nd largest value if largest is infinity

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

```
      country_code  count_date  confirmed_cases  growth_rate
0              AFG  2020-09-18          38872.0    94.019934
1              AFG  2020-09-17          38855.0    83.641975
2              AFG  2020-09-16          38815.0   108.154506
3              AFG  2020-09-15          38772.0   196.296296
4              AFG  2020-09-14          38716.0   196.894410
...            ...         ...              ...          ...
20451          ZWE  2020-06-03            206.0          NaN
20452          ZWE  2020-06-02            203.0          NaN
20453          ZWE  2020-06-01            178.0          NaN
20454          ZWE  2020-05-31            174.0          NaN
20455          ZWE  2020-05-30            149.0          NaN
```

I am trying to do this:
`df.groupby('count_date').growth_rate.transform(lambda x: x/x.max())`

But some of the `x.max()` values are infinity and in such cases I want to use the 2nd largest value. How do I convert the below pseudo-code to actual code:

`df.groupby('count_date').growth_rate.transform(lambda x: x/x.max() if x.max() != inf else x/<2nd largest>)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a mask to drop inf values from x :

```py
df.groupby('count_date').growth_rate.transform(lambda x: x/x[~np.isinf(x)].max())
```

Here is an example:

```py
# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'count_date': ['2020-09-17', '2020-09-17', '2020-09-17', '2020-09-17'],
    'growth_rate': [ 1, 3, 2, np.inf]
})

df.groupby('count_date').growth_rate.transform(lambda x: x/x[~np.isinf(x)].max())
0    0.333333
1    1.000000
2    0.666667
3         inf
```

As you can see, the scaling was performed using the largest non infinity value found in x.

Comment: Just for educational purposes I would also like to see how we can do this with `if/else`. May not be you but hope someone else comes up with that.

Comment: Sure ! The structure would be : df.groupby('count_date').growth_rate.transform(lambda x: x/x.max() 
                                               if len(x[np.isinf(x)]) == 0
                                               else x/x[~np.isinf(x)].max())

Comment: Is there any way to access the 2nd largest value in place of `x.max()`. I tried `x.nlargest(2)[1]` but it doesnt work.

Comment: You can use x.nlargest(2).iloc[1]. Your code uses an index but you must rather use .iloc to get the position